# Add or modify a nullptr Vector from a partially filled flatbuffer?

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

This builds off of the monster schema example. If I partially fill a flatbuffer such as in the official [test.cpp](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/615616cb5549a34bdf288c04bc1b94bd7a65c396/tests/test.cpp#L169-L177).

Relevant lines also copied below

```cpp
// Create a mostly empty FlatBuffer.
flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder nested_builder;
auto nmloc = CreateMonster(nested_builder, nullptr, 0, 0,
                           nested_builder.CreateString("NestedMonster"));
FinishMonsterBuffer(nested_builder, nmloc);
```

How can I modify the inventory part of the schema from nested_builder after already calling `FinishMonsterBuffer(nested_builder, nmloc);`?

Things I've tried (related to [test.cpp](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/615616cb5549a34bdf288c04bc1b94bd7a65c396/tests/test.cpp#L1064-L1085)):

```cpp
std::string bfbsfile;
bool found = flatbuffers::LoadFile( "./monster_schema.bfbs", true, &bfbsfile );
const reflection::Schema& schema = *reflection::GetSchema( bfbsfile.c_str() );
auto root_table = schema.root_table();

auto fields = root_table->fields();

// The above works fine I've tested the fields and verified the schema.
// I'm unsure of the code below.

// First we put the FlatBuffer inside an std::vector.
std::vector<uint8_t> resizingbuf(
    nested_builder.GetBufferPointer(), 
    nested_builder.GetBufferPointer() + nested_builder.GetSize());
// Get the root.
// This time we wrap the result from GetAnyRoot in a smartpointer that
// will keep rroot valid as resizingbuf resizes.
auto rroot = flatbuffers::piv(flatbuffers::GetAnyRoot(resizingbuf.data()),
                              resizingbuf);
// Now lets try to extend a vector by 100 elements (0 -> 110).
auto &inventory_field = *fields->LookupByKey("inventory");
// I don't think this works either if it doesn't already exist.
auto rinventory = flatbuffers::piv(
     flatbuffers::GetFieldV<uint8_t>(**rroot, inventory_field), resizingbuf);

// This line silently fails probably because *rinventory is probably a nullptr  
// but I don't know how to set it after having already 
// called FinishMonsterBuffer(nested_builder, nmloc);.
flatbuffers::ResizeVector<uint8_t>(schema, 110, 50, *rinventory,
                                   &resizingbuf);
// Try to print it but prints nothing.
// printf("%hhu", rinventory->Get(10));
```

Apologies in advance for the title I'm not quite sure how to phrase the exact problem or question.
Let me know if more context is needed or part of the question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer*: Flatbuffers doesn't generally allow mutating a vector after the buffer has been finished. However, we do have some advanced APIs in the reflection API for doing such mutations, but are generally slow and not recommended.

We don't support the case of resizing a `null` vector. We store `null` within the vtable and there is no data/size information in the buffer related to a `null` vector. Therefore there is nothing to resize.

You may try inserting a empty vector instead, as that should place the necessary data/size information into the buffer that can be later resized.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! Quick follow-up when you say to insert an empty vector do you mean to insert it during creation or is there a way to insert an empty vector after calling Finish() ? If it's the latter is there an easy example?

Comment: You couldn't add it after calling Finish(), as that finalizes the buffer and is not longer editable. You would have to do it in your call: `CreateMonster(nested_builder, nullptr, 0, 0,
                           nested_builder.CreateString("NestedMonster"));` replace the nullptr with an empty vector.